# API return JSON assigned to javaScript variable. How to read that JSON?

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

I'm using Tumblr v1 API (https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v1). I used https://app.quicktype.io to prepare all structs for that particular JSON. At that documentation you can find, returned JSON is assigned to javaScript variable. I don't know how to read data from that variable/JSON. When I tried to read some parameters error appeared: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
Do you have any idea how to read that JSON?

```
    let baseUrl = ".tumblr.com/api/read/json"
    let https = "https://"
    let userName = "timberland"
    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()

    guard let mainUrl = URL(string: https + userName + baseUrl) else { return }
    let urlSession = URLSession.shared

    urlSession.dataTask(with: mainUrl) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { return }
        if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let myPost = try jsonDecoder.decode(TumblrJSON.self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print(myPost.posts[0].id)
                }
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
```

and JSON structs

```
    struct TumblrJSON: Codable {
    let tumblelog: TumblrJSONTumblelog
    let postsStart, postsTotal: Int
    let postsType: Bool
    let posts: [Post]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case tumblelog
        case postsStart = "posts-start"
        case postsTotal = "posts-total"
        case postsType = "posts-type"
        case posts
    }
}

struct Post: Codable {
    let id: String
    let url, urlWithSlug: String
    let type, dateGmt, date: String
    let bookmarklet, mobile: Int
    let feedItem: String
    let fromFeedID, unixTimestamp: Int
    let format, reblogKey, slug: String
    let isSubmission: Bool
    let likeButton, reblogButton, state, noteCount: String
    let tumblelog: PostTumblelog
    let regularTitle, regularBody: String
    let tags: [String]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, url
        case urlWithSlug = "url-with-slug"
        case type
        case dateGmt = "date-gmt"
        case date, bookmarklet, mobile
        case feedItem = "feed-item"
        case fromFeedID = "from-feed-id"
        case unixTimestamp = "unix-timestamp"
        case format
        case reblogKey = "reblog-key"
        case slug
        case isSubmission = "is-submission"
        case likeButton = "like-button"
        case reblogButton = "reblog-button"
        case state
        case noteCount = "note-count"
        case tumblelog
        case regularTitle = "regular-title"
        case regularBody = "regular-body"
        case tags
    }
}

struct PostTumblelog: Codable {
    let title, name: String
    let cname: Bool
    let url: String
    let timezone: String
    let avatarURL512, avatarURL128, avatarURL96, avatarURL64: String
    let avatarURL48, avatarURL40, avatarURL30, avatarURL24: String
    let avatarURL16: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title, name, cname, url, timezone
        case avatarURL512 = "avatar_url_512"
        case avatarURL128 = "avatar_url_128"
        case avatarURL96 = "avatar_url_96"
        case avatarURL64 = "avatar_url_64"
        case avatarURL48 = "avatar_url_48"
        case avatarURL40 = "avatar_url_40"
        case avatarURL30 = "avatar_url_30"
        case avatarURL24 = "avatar_url_24"
        case avatarURL16 = "avatar_url_16"
    }
}

struct TumblrJSONTumblelog: Codable {
    let title, description, name, timezone: String
    let cname: Bool
}
```

JSON Value

```
var tumblr_api_read = {"tumblelog":{"title":"Timberland","description":"","name":"timberland","timezone":"US\/Eastern","cname":false,"feeds":[]},"posts-start":0,"posts-total":493,"posts-type":false,"posts":[{"id":"132163144823","url":"http:\/\/timberland.tumblr.com\/post\/132163144823","url-with-slug":"http:\/\/timberland.tumblr.com\/post\/132163144823\/publish-x-timberland-collaboration-coming","type":"photo","date-gmt":"2015-10-29 19:33:36 GMT","date":"Thu, 29 Oct 2015 15:33:36","bookmarklet":0,"mobile":0,"feed-item":"","from-feed-id":0,"unix-timestamp":1446147216,"format":"html","reblog-key":"tG24PRhC","slug":"publish-x-timberland-collaboration-coming","is-submission":false,"like-button":"<div class=\"like_button\" data-post-id=\"132163144823\" data-blog-name=\"timberland\" id=\"like_button_132163144823\"><iframe id=\"like_iframe_132163144823\" src=\"https:\/\/assets.tumblr.com\/assets\/html\/like_iframe.html?_v=66c22ab5319d742bca5762b8d18f9d06#name=timberland&amp;post_id=132163144823&amp;color=black&amp;rk=tG24PRhC\" scrolling=\"no\" width=\"20\" height=\"20\" frameborder=\"0\" class=\"like_toggle\" allowTransparency=\"true\" name=\"like_iframe_132163144823\"><\/iframe><\/div>","reblog-button":"<a href=\"https:\/\/www.tumblr.com\/reblog\/132163144823\/tG24PRhC\" class=\"reblog_button\"style=\"display: block;width:20px;height:20px;\"><svg width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" viewBox=\"0 0 21 21\" xmlns=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2000\/svg\" xmlns:xlink=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/1999\/xlink\" fill=\"#000\"><path d=\"M5.01092527,5.99908429 L16.0088498,5.99908429 L16.136,9.508 L20.836,4.752 L16.136,0.083 L16.1360004,3.01110845 L2.09985349,3.01110845 C1.50585349,3.01110845 0.979248041,3.44726568 0.979248041,4.45007306 L0.979248041,10.9999998 L3.98376463,8.30993634 L3.98376463,6.89801007 C3.98376463,6.20867902 4.71892527,5.99908429 5.01092527,5.99908429 Z\"><\/path><path d=\"M17.1420002,13.2800293 C17.1420002,13.5720293 17.022957,14.0490723 16.730957,14.0490723 L4.92919922,14.0490723 L4.92919922,11 L0.5,15.806 L4.92919922,20.5103758 L5.00469971,16.9990234 L18.9700928,16.9990234 C19.5640928,16.9990234 19.9453125,16.4010001 19.9453125,15.8060001 L19.9453125,9.5324707 L17.142,12.203\"><\/path><\/svg><\/a>","note-count":"70","tumblelog":{"title":"Timberland","name":"timberland","cname":false,"url":"http:\/\/timberland.tumblr.com\/","timezone":"US\/Eastern","avatar_url_512":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_571109f21077_512.png","avatar_url_128":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_571109f21077_128.png","avatar_url_96":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_571109f21077_96.png","avatar_url_64":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_571109f21077_64.png","avatar_url_48":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_571109f21077_48.png","avatar_url_40":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_571109f21077_40.png","avatar_url_30":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_571109f21077_30.png","avatar_url_24":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_571109f21077_24.png","avatar_url_16":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_571109f21077_16.png"},"photo-caption":"<b>Publish X Timberland Collaboration<\/b><br\/><br\/><p>Coming November 7: our latest collaboration with Publish Brand. Mark your calendars. <\/p><p>\n        (via <a href=\"http:\/\/pco.lt\/1O3sTq4\">Publish X Timberland Collaboration<\/a>)\n    <\/p>","width":520,"height":347,"photo-url-1280":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/55f5b1f0f1076924a8f6221740f430b1\/tumblr_nwzyc074G11r6oj70o1_540.jpg","photo-url-500":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/55f5b1f0f1076924a8f6221740f430b1\/tumblr_nwzyc074G11r6oj70o1_500.jpg","photo-url-400":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/55f5b1f0f1076924a8f6221740f430b1\/tumblr_nwzyc074G11r6oj70o1_400.jpg","photo-url-250":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/55f5b1f0f1076924a8f6221740f430b1\/tumblr_nwzyc074G11r6oj70o1_250.jpg","photo-url-100":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/55f5b1f0f1076924a8f6221740f430b1\/tumblr_nwzyc074G11r6oj70o1_100.jpg","photo-url-75":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/55f5b1f0f1076924a8f6221740f430b1\/tumblr_nwzyc074G11r6oj70o1_75sq.jpg","photos":[],"tags":["collab","timberland","publishbrand","timberlandxpublish"]}]};
```

Comment: Show me your JSON value. Then i can help you

Comment: I added JSON Structs to description. I can't attach obtained data, because even for one Post it has too many characters. It's a HTML code. After decoding I can't print decoded JSON due to mentioned error. I added JSON returned by API to description as well

Comment: Your problems based on that you didn't encode your html strings before insert to your json string in backend. It mess to create good data from string.

Answer (score 0):

You have a very peculiar situation, ideally we should get the JSON in the correct format but if you are in this situation.

What we can do here is get the responseSting and split it to get the Actual JSON and then Convert that to data again for `JSONDecoder`

Update your `dataTask` as

```
urlSession.dataTask(with: mainUrl) { (data, response, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { return }
    if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {

            if let stringData = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8),
                // Splitting the String to get the actual JSON
                var json = stringData.components(separatedBy: "tumblr_api_read = ").last {

                // Removing the ";" at the end
                json.remove(at: json.index(before: String.Index(encodedOffset: json.count - 1)))

                print(json)

                let jsonData = json.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!

                let myPost = try jsonDecoder.decode(TumblrJSON.self, from: jsonData)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print(myPost.posts[0].id)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    }.resume()
```

Plus Edit your struts to support nil values as some of the data in the json is nil

```
struct Post: Codable {
    let id: String?
    let url, urlWithSlug: String?
    let type, dateGmt, date: String?
    let bookmarklet, mobile: Int?
    let feedItem: String?
    let fromFeedID, unixTimestamp: Int?
    let format, reblogKey, slug: String?
    let isSubmission: Bool?
    let likeButton, reblogButton, state, noteCount: String?
    let tumblelog: PostTumblelog?
    let regularTitle, regularBody: String?
    let tags: [String]?
}

struct PostTumblelog: Codable {
    let title, name: String?
    let cname: Bool?
    let url: String?
    let timezone: String?
    let avatarURL512, avatarURL128, avatarURL96, avatarURL64: String?
    let avatarURL48, avatarURL40, avatarURL30, avatarURL24: String?
    let avatarURL16: String?
}
```

**Edit**

Copy all your code from here into the Project or simply a playground, its 100% working

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct TumblrJSON: Codable {
    let tumblelog: TumblrJSONTumblelog
    let postsStart, postsTotal: Int
    let postsType: Bool
    let posts: [Post]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case tumblelog
        case postsStart = "posts-start"
        case postsTotal = "posts-total"
        case postsType = "posts-type"
        case posts
    }
}

struct Post: Codable {
    let id: String?
    let url, urlWithSlug: String?
    let type, dateGmt, date: String?
    let bookmarklet, mobile: Int?
    let feedItem: String?
    let fromFeedID, unixTimestamp: Int?
    let format, reblogKey, slug: String?
    let isSubmission: Bool?
    let likeButton, reblogButton, state, noteCount: String?
    let tumblelog: PostTumblelog?
    let regularTitle, regularBody: String?
    let tags: [String]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, url
        case urlWithSlug = "url-with-slug"
        case type
        case dateGmt = "date-gmt"
        case date, bookmarklet, mobile
        case feedItem = "feed-item"
        case fromFeedID = "from-feed-id"
        case unixTimestamp = "unix-timestamp"
        case format
        case reblogKey = "reblog-key"
        case slug
        case isSubmission = "is-submission"
        case likeButton = "like-button"
        case reblogButton = "reblog-button"
        case state
        case noteCount = "note-count"
        case tumblelog
        case regularTitle = "regular-title"
        case regularBody = "regular-body"
        case tags
    }
}

struct PostTumblelog: Codable {
    let title, name: String?
    let cname: Bool?
    let url: String?
    let timezone: String?
    let avatarURL512, avatarURL128, avatarURL96, avatarURL64: String?
    let avatarURL48, avatarURL40, avatarURL30, avatarURL24: String?
    let avatarURL16: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title, name, cname, url, timezone
        case avatarURL512 = "avatar_url_512"
        case avatarURL128 = "avatar_url_128"
        case avatarURL96 = "avatar_url_96"
        case avatarURL64 = "avatar_url_64"
        case avatarURL48 = "avatar_url_48"
        case avatarURL40 = "avatar_url_40"
        case avatarURL30 = "avatar_url_30"
        case avatarURL24 = "avatar_url_24"
        case avatarURL16 = "avatar_url_16"
    }
}

struct TumblrJSONTumblelog: Codable {
    let title, description, name, timezone: String
    let cname: Bool
}

let baseUrl = ".tumblr.com/api/read/json"
let https = "https://"
let userName = "timberland"
let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()

let mainUrl = URL(string: https + userName + baseUrl)!
let urlSession = URLSession.shared

urlSession.dataTask(with: mainUrl) { (data, response, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { return }
    if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {

            if let stringData = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8),
                // Splitting the String to get the actual JSON
                var json = stringData.components(separatedBy: "tumblr_api_read = ").last {

                // Removing the ";" at the end
                json.remove(at: json.index(before: String.Index(encodedOffset: json.count - 1)))

                print(json)

                let jsonData = json.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!

                let myPost = try jsonDecoder.decode(TumblrJSON.self, from: jsonData)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print(myPost.posts[0].id!)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    }.resume()
```

Comment: Im assuming the codable structs have no issues, even if they do it wont be more than a textual change, hope this helps

Comment: It doesn't help. Still when trying to decode data error is appearing: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Comment: @iMat The JSON is returning nil values, so you have to make your variables `Optionals`  Edited the answer to reflect the change, This will do the trick

Comment: @iMat, try changing `print(error.localizedDescription)` to `print(error)`. That will show you more info about the error.

Comment: @iMat you are missing something while copying as i have all the code running perfectly and `print(myPost.posts[0].id!)` is printing `132163144823`

Comment: @RaziTiwana, your code would work in most cases, but some string item may contain " = ". When you received such data, your code will not work.

Comment: @OOPer yeah but this is mainly to give an idea, as i don't know the nature of the response, but we can solve this by using the sting "var tumblr_api_read = " instead of " = " , But then again this would need the assumption that the "tumblr_api_read" will remain the same. All that can only be answered/ suggested after through review of the Api.

Comment: @RaziTiwana, **_this would need the assumption that the "tumblr_api_read" will remain the same_** It is clearly documented in the API doc.

Comment: @OOPer i left that part for the OP but on your Authority i'll edit the answer, Thanks

Comment: @iMat i've made an edit to the answer on the suggestion of OOPer

Comment: @RaziTiwana, IMO using `components(separatedBy:)` is still unsafe, but _left that part for the OP_ is a reasonable opinion, seems I should leave it for you two.

Comment: @RaziTiwana i checked your solution and print error instead of error.localizedString:
JSON Decoding Error: dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.})))

Comment: @iMat i added the whole file for you in the answer that is working at my end, kindly copy and paste the whole thing and it should work, try running this in a `playground` so you can be sure

Comment: @RaziTiwana I used your whole code at Project and Playground. For both cases I found error when trying to decode a JSON:
dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.})))

Comment: I found an issue.
It is related to GDPR, if I'm using request from Safari where im logged to my Tumblr account all works fine, byt when I used Xcode's simulator or private tab at safari I got HTML with info about GDPR, on that I have to Accept rules to got proper JSON. Thats why I can't decode downloaded data. THANKS for help

Answer (score 0):

Here is correct answer with correct structs:

```
struct MyJsonStruct: Codable {
    let tumblelog: PostTumblelog?
    let postsStart: Int?
    let postsTotal: Int?
    let postsType: Bool?
    let posts : [Post]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case tumblelog = "tumblelog"
        case postsStart = "posts-start"
        case postsTotal = "posts-total"
        case postsType = "posts-type"
        case posts
    }
}

struct Post: Codable {
    let id: String?
    let url, urlWithSlug: String?
    let type, dateGmt, date: String?
    let bookmarklet, mobile: Int?
    let feedItem: String?
    let fromFeedID, unixTimestamp: Int?
    let format, reblogKey, slug: String?
    let isSubmission: Bool?
    let likeButton, reblogButton, state, noteCount: String?
    let tumblelog: PostTumblelog?
    let photoCaption: String?
    let width, height: Int?
    let tags: [String]?
    let photoUrl1280 : String?
    let photoUrl500 : String?
    let photoUrl400 : String?
    let photoUrl250 : String?
    let photoUrl100 : String?
    let photoUrl75 : String?
    let photos : [String]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, url
        case urlWithSlug = "url-with-slug"
        case type
        case dateGmt = "date-gmt"
        case date, bookmarklet, mobile
        case feedItem = "feed-item"
        case fromFeedID = "from-feed-id"
        case unixTimestamp = "unix-timestamp"
        case format
        case reblogKey = "reblog-key"
        case slug
        case isSubmission = "is-submission"
        case likeButton = "like-button"
        case reblogButton = "reblog-button"
        case state
        case noteCount = "note-count"
        case tumblelog
        case photoCaption = "photo-caption"
        case width, height
        case photoUrl1280 = "photo-url-1280"
        case photoUrl500 = "photo-url-500"
        case photoUrl400 = "photo-url-400"
        case photoUrl250 = "photo-url-250"
        case photoUrl100 = "photo-url-100"
        case photoUrl75 = "photo-url-75"
        case photos
        case tags
    }
}

struct PostTumblelog: Codable {
    let title, name: String?
    let description : String? = ""
    let cname: Bool?
    let url: String?
    let timezone: String?
    let feeds : [String]? = []
    let avatarURL512, avatarURL128, avatarURL96, avatarURL64: String?
    let avatarURL48, avatarURL40, avatarURL30, avatarURL24: String?
    let avatarURL16: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title, name, cname, url, timezone
        case avatarURL512 = "avatar_url_512"
        case avatarURL128 = "avatar_url_128"
        case avatarURL96 = "avatar_url_96"
        case avatarURL64 = "avatar_url_64"
        case avatarURL48 = "avatar_url_48"
        case avatarURL40 = "avatar_url_40"
        case avatarURL30 = "avatar_url_30"
        case avatarURL24 = "avatar_url_24"
        case avatarURL16 = "avatar_url_16"
    }
}
```

I call decoder like here below:

```
    let jsonData = json.data(using: .utf8)!
    do {

        let myPost = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyJsonStruct.self, from: jsonData)

        print(myPost)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

Also, you have build json string in incorrect way: **You need to encode html strings before insert to json string in backend**, see an example:

```
<b>Publish X Timberland Collaboration</b><br/><br/><p>Coming November 7: our latest collaboration with Publish Brand. Mark your calendars. </p><p>

    </p>
```

need to encode to

```
%3Cb%3EPublish+X+Timberland+Collaboration%3C%2Fb%3E%3Cbr%2F%3E%3Cbr%2F%3E%3Cp%3EComing+November+7%3A+our+latest+collaboration+with+Publish+Brand.+Mark+your+calendars.+%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3E%0D%0A++++++++%0D%0A++++%3C%2Fp%3E
```

At last, I replaced "\/" occurences to "/" to make a good json string.
After that you can easily work with json data in swift.

And than we have json string like this:

```
var json = """
{"tumblelog": {"title": "Timberland","description": "","name": "timberland","timezone": "US/Eastern","cname": false,"feeds": []},"posts-start": 0,"posts-total": 493,"posts-type": false,"posts": [{"id": "132163144823","url": "http://timberland.tumblr.com/post/132163144823","url-with-slug": "http://timberland.tumblr.com/post/132163144823/publish-x-timberland-collaboration-coming","type": "photo","date-gmt": "2015-10-29 19:33:36 GMT","date": "Thu, 29 Oct 2015 15:33:36","bookmarklet": 0,"mobile": 0,"feed-item": "","from-feed-id": 0,"unix-timestamp": 1446147216,"format": "html","reblog-key": "tG24PRhC","slug": "publish-x-timberland-collaboration-coming","is-submission": false,"like-button": "%3Cdiv%20class%3D%5C%22like_button%5C%22%20data-post-id%3D%5C%22132163144823%5C%22%20data-blog-name%3D%5C%22timberland%5C%22%20id%3D%5C%22like_button_132163144823%5C%22%3E%3Ciframe%20id%3D%5C%22like_iframe_132163144823%5C%22%20src%3D%5C%22https%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fassets.tumblr.com%5C%2Fassets%5C%2Fhtml%5C%2Flike_iframe.html%3F_v%3D66c22ab5319d742bca5762b8d18f9d06%23name%3Dtimberland%26amp%3Bpost_id%3D132163144823%26amp%3Bcolor%3Dblack%26amp%3Brk%3DtG24PRhC%5C%22%20scrolling%3D%5C%22no%5C%22%20width%3D%5C%2220%5C%22%20height%3D%5C%2220%5C%22%20frameborder%3D%5C%220%5C%22%20class%3D%5C%22like_toggle%5C%22%20allowTransparency%3D%5C%22true%5C%22%20name%3D%5C%22like_iframe_132163144823%5C%22%3E%3C%5C%2Fiframe%3E%3C%5C%2Fdiv%3E","reblog-button": "%3Ca%20href%3D%5C%22https%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fwww.tumblr.com%5C%2Freblog%5C%2F132163144823%5C%2FtG24PRhC%5C%22%20class%3D%5C%22reblog_button%5C%22style%3D%5C%22display%3A%20block%3Bwidth%3A20px%3Bheight%3A20px%3B%5C%22%3E%3Csvg%20width%3D%5C%22100%25%5C%22%20height%3D%5C%22100%25%5C%22%20viewBox%3D%5C%220%200%2021%2021%5C%22%20xmlns%3D%5C%22http%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fwww.w3.org%5C%2F2000%5C%2Fsvg%5C%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%5C%22http%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fwww.w3.org%5C%2F1999%5C%2Fxlink%5C%22%20fill%3D%5C%22%23000%5C%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%5C%22M5.01092527%2C5.99908429%20L16.0088498%2C5.99908429%20L16.136%2C9.508%20L20.836%2C4.752%20L16.136%2C0.083%20L16.1360004%2C3.01110845%20L2.09985349%2C3.01110845%20C1.50585349%2C3.01110845%200.979248041%2C3.44726568%200.979248041%2C4.45007306%20L0.979248041%2C10.9999998%20L3.98376463%2C8.30993634%20L3.98376463%2C6.89801007%20C3.98376463%2C6.20867902%204.71892527%2C5.99908429%205.01092527%2C5.99908429%20Z%5C%22%3E%3C%5C%2Fpath%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%5C%22M17.1420002%2C13.2800293%20C17.1420002%2C13.5720293%2017.022957%2C14.0490723%2016.730957%2C14.0490723%20L4.92919922%2C14.0490723%20L4.92919922%2C11%20L0.5%2C15.806%20L4.92919922%2C20.5103758%20L5.00469971%2C16.9990234%20L18.9700928%2C16.9990234%20C19.5640928%2C16.9990234%2019.9453125%2C16.4010001%2019.9453125%2C15.8060001%20L19.9453125%2C9.5324707%20L17.142%2C12.203%5C%22%3E%3C%5C%2Fpath%3E%3C%5C%2Fsvg%3E%3C%5C%2Fa%3E","note-count": "70","tumblelog": {"title": "Timberland","name": "timberland","cname": false,"url": "http://timberland.tumblr.com/","timezone": "US/Eastern","avatar_url_512": "https://66.media.tumblr.com/avatar_571109f21077_512.png","avatar_url_128": "https://66.media.tumblr.com/avatar_571109f21077_128.png","avatar_url_96": "https://66.media.tumblr.com/avatar_571109f21077_96.png","avatar_url_64": "https://66.media.tumblr.com/avatar_571109f21077_64.png","avatar_url_48": "https://66.media.tumblr.com/avatar_571109f21077_48.png","avatar_url_40": "https://66.media.tumblr.com/avatar_571109f21077_40.png","avatar_url_30": "https://66.media.tumblr.com/avatar_571109f21077_30.png","avatar_url_24": "https://66.media.tumblr.com/avatar_571109f21077_24.png","avatar_url_16": "https://66.media.tumblr.com/avatar_571109f21077_16.png"},"photo-caption": "%3Cb%3EPublish%20X%20Timberland%20Collaboration%3C%5C%2Fb%3E%3Cbr%5C%2F%3E%3Cbr%5C%2F%3E%3Cp%3EComing%20November%207%3A%20our%20latest%20collaboration%20with%20Publish%20Brand.%20Mark%20your%20calendars.%20%3C%5C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(via%20%3Ca%20href%3D%5C%22http%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fpco.lt%5C%2F1O3sTq4%5C%22%3EPublish%20X%20Timberland%20Collaboration%3C%5C%2Fa%3E)%5Cn%20%20%20%20%3C%5C%2Fp%3E","width": 520,"height": 347,"photo-url-1280": "https://66.media.tumblr.com/55f5b1f0f1076924a8f6221740f430b1/tumblr_nwzyc074G11r6oj70o1_540.jpg","photo-url-500": "https://66.media.tumblr.com/55f5b1f0f1076924a8f6221740f430b1/tumblr_nwzyc074G11r6oj70o1_500.jpg","photo-url-400": "https://66.media.tumblr.com/55f5b1f0f1076924a8f6221740f430b1/tumblr_nwzyc074G11r6oj70o1_400.jpg","photo-url-250": "https://66.media.tumblr.com/55f5b1f0f1076924a8f6221740f430b1/tumblr_nwzyc074G11r6oj70o1_250.jpg","photo-url-100": "https://66.media.tumblr.com/55f5b1f0f1076924a8f6221740f430b1/tumblr_nwzyc074G11r6oj70o1_100.jpg","photo-url-75": "https://66.media.tumblr.com/55f5b1f0f1076924a8f6221740f430b1/tumblr_nwzyc074G11r6oj70o1_75sq.jpg","photos": [],"tags": ["collab", "timberland", "publishbrand", "timberlandxpublish"]}]}
"""
```